# How to show error on console while logging it to both log file and console in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to log messages to both console and a log file in a bash script. I am able to log the stdout message both in console and log file but not a stderr. Below is the script and output. Please help.

**Script:**

```
!/bin/bash
LOG_FILE='./test1.log'
exec 3>&1 1>>${LOG_FILE} 2>&1
echo "log to console and log file" | tee /dev/fd/3
echo "only to log file"
chmm 777 ${LOG_FILE}
```

**Log file:**

```
log to console and log file
only to log file
./log_to_console_and_file.sh: line 6: chmm: command not found
```

Console:

```
log to console and log file
```

I want the below error message to be shown in the console as well.

```
./log_to_console_and_file.sh: line 6: chmm: command not found
```

Thanks.

Comment: chmm ? To change permission, use "chmod"

Comment: Are you even using a console?  Most terminals are not consoles: https://superuser.com/questions/144666/what-is-the-difference-between-shell-console-and-terminal/144668#144668

Comment: Also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4126/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-a-terminal-a-shell-a-tty-and-a-con/4132#4132

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand well you'd like to send `stderr` to the console and to the log file, `stdout` only to the log file, plus be able to send messages both to the log file and the console with `echo ... | tee /dev/fd/3`.

To send `stderr` to the console and to the log file simply redirect it to a `tee -a "$LOG_FILE"` command using process substitution. Then make a copy of `stdout` to `fd3` and redirect (append) `stdout` to the log file:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

LOG_FILE='./test1.log'
exec 2> >( tee -a "$LOG_FILE" ) 3>&1 1>>"$LOG_FILE"

echo "log to console and log file" | tee /dev/fd/3
echo "only to log file"
chmm 777 ${LOG_FILE}
```

Demo:

```sh
$ ./log_to_console_and_file.sh
log to console and log file
./log_to_console_and_file.sh: line 8: chmm: command not found
$ cat test1.log 
log to console and log file
only to log file
./log_to_console_and_file.sh: line 8: chmm: command not found
```

Of course you know already that the order of redirections matters.

Note that your shebang (`!/bin/bash`) is incorrect. Note also that as `stderr` now appends to console and log file you don't really need `fd3` any more. To send something to console and log file you could probably simply redirect it to `stderr`...

Comment: The solution you have provided has worked. just a small note, on Amazon Linux version I had to remove spaces in redirection as "1>>"$LOG_FILE".

Comment: @RobWilkinson Interesting. I don't remember having encountered this before. But as the bash manual says `[n]>>word` I guess it is better to remove theses spaces. I edit my answer.

Comment: please note that I have tried the same exec command as part of AWS SSM command shell script and got an issue. Not sure why it is failing, so asked another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69488584/shell-script-is-giving-error-while-running-as-part-of-aws-ssm-command